# How to split integer and sum the splitted integer using python?

Tags: python

I have given a task in python language that i should split the given numbers into 2 half and sum each of the 2 half. For example:

```
input = 1234
output must be 1 + 2 = 3 and 3 + 4 = 7. means 3 & 7.
```

Explanation: I have to split the given input 1234 to 12 and 34.

and then i have to sum 1 + 2 and 3 + 4. and the final output will be 37.

PS: here is what i tried myself. I am new to python.

```
#T = int(raw_input())
#while T > 0 :
#    input = raw_input()
#    i = []
#    i.append(input)
```

Comment: Have you tried to solve it yourself?

Comment: without trying i wont come here.

Comment: OK, show your attempts.

Comment: @nasr18 great. Want to share your code?

Comment: here is what i tried..... actually i am new to python....#T = int(raw_input())
#while T > 0 :
#    input = raw_input()
#    i = []
#    i.append(input)

Comment: Please add this code to the question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
data = input()
# Divide the list
div = len(data)//2
lst = []
# Add both halves to the list
lst.append(data[:div])
lst.append(data[div:])
tot = ""
# Loop through the list and add the sum as a string
for i in lst:
    tot += str(int(i[0])+int(i[1]))
# Print the final string
print(tot)
```

Comment: is there any way to check whether the sum of first half is equal to the sum of second half???? I mean 1 + 2 = 3 is equal to 3 + 4 = 7.

Comment: change tot to a list and add integers to the list in the for loop. then check if the first element in the list is equal to the second (tot[0]==tot[1])